# How can i retrieve datas of my checkboxes

Tags: php, jquery

I am having a problem with reading the data in checkboxes. I did some research on the net and found the below code. This code is for *removing* data with checkboxes though.

```
function deleteData()
{
    var artistIds = new Array();

    $(".p16 input:checked").each(function(){
        artistIds.push($(this).attr('id'));
    });
var sitepath = 'http://www.sinemalar.com/';

$.post('/json/crewonly/deleteDataAjax2', 
       { json: JSON.stringify({'artistIds': artistIds}) },
       function(response){
        alert("Başarıyla silindi");
        window.location.replace(window.location.pathname);
});
```

[image]

and this is the code which produces checkboxes.

```
{foreach value=artist2 from=$artist}



        <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="artist[]" value="{$artist2.MOVIE_ID}-{$artist2.PERSON_ID}" { in_array array=$item match=$artist2.NAME_SURNAME returnvalue="CHECKED" }>{$artist2.NAME_SURNAME}<br />
        <hr />



        {/foreach}
```

The person who wrote this code uses this to read checkboxes.  Do i have to use `<p>` to read my checkbox values or is there an alternative way? 
    .p16 input:checked

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var checkedBoxesArr = [];
  $("input[name='artist[]']").each(function() {
     if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        checkedBoxesArr.push($(this).val());
     }
  });
});
```